# How should I design the multiple same applications update one database

Tags: database

I'm managing an online book store website. For sake of high availability I've setup two Tomcat instances for running the website application, they are the exactly same program, and they are sharing the same database which located in another server.

My question is that how can I avoid conflicts or dirty data when the two applications do the same updates/inserts at the same time to the database.

For example: `update t_sale set total='${num}' where category='cs'`, if there are two processes execute the above sql simultaneously would cause data lost.

Answer (score 0):

If by "database" you are talking about a well designed schema that is running on an RDBMS such as Oracle, DB2, or SQL Server, then the database itself will prevent what you call "conflicts" by locking parts of the database during each update transaction.

You can prevent "dirty data" from getting into the database by adding features such as check clauses and primary-foreign key structures in the database itself.